# Rust Dummy Future Value?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a use case where I need to specify a dummy Future to make a type concrete. The use case is I have a struct which takes a generic parameter, which is a Future:

```
let thing = Thing<Fut>::some_method().await?;
```

`some_method` is a method on `Thing` which does not use the `Fut` at all, but the compiler complains because of the compiler limitations such that the type can't be inferred and is necessary because of the async block.

Since I need a concrete sized thing for `Fut`, I was hoping there was something in futures_util that I could use. Right now, this is my very bad approach:

```
use futures::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

struct Thing<Fut>
where
    for<'b> Fut: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'b,
{
    callback: dyn Fn() -> Fut + Send + Sync,
}

impl<Fut> Thing<Fut> where for<'b> Fut: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'b {
    async fn some_method(a: i32) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        println!("I am some_method with value {}", a);
        Ok(())
    }
}

struct Dummy {
}

impl Future for Dummy {
    type Output = ();
        fn poll(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Self::Output> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // this fails
    Thing::some_method(3).await.unwrap();
    
    // this works
    //Thing::<Dummy>::some_method(3).await.unwrap();
}
```

Is there something I can leverage here to make such a dummy value available?

Here is a minimal playground example:
[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=380a17958e6ad802cfa1289b3fc71bfc)

The error:

```
error[E0698]: type inside `async` block must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:33:5
   |
33 |     Thing::some_method(3).await.unwrap();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `Fut`
   |
note: the type is part of the `async` block because of this `await`
  --> src/main.rs:33:26
   |
33 |     Thing::some_method(3).await.unwrap();
   |                          ^^^^^^
```

If you uncomment the success line, it will remove the error.

Comment: Would [`std::future::ready`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/fn.ready.html) work for you?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example along with the compiler error you're seeing.

Comment: @PitaJ unfortunately, I need a concrete type. Added a playground example.

Comment: For future reference: you should embed the playground code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::future::Ready`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/future/struct.Ready.html) (or probably `Pending` alternatively). This is the type returned by the `std::future::ready` function.

```rust
use std::future::Ready;

type Dummy = Ready<()>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    Thing::<Dummy>::some_method(3).await.unwrap();
}
```

But if this function has no dependence on `Fut`, then I'd question why it's an associated function on `Thing` in the first place. Maybe it should be a free-standing function instead.

Comment: doh, I'm so tired.... Thanks.